# Given a convex set, does there always exist a convex function whose 0-sublevel set is the convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis

Given a convex set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$,
can one always construct a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that its $0$-sublevel set $\{ u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} | f(u) \leq 0 \}$ is the convex set $U$?

Comment: Ah, I think the distance to the convex set $U$ is a convex function which renders that the $0$-sublevel set is $U$...!

Comment: You need to assume that $U$ is closed. Such a convex function will be continuous...

Comment: @daw Does the closedness affect when $ f(u) =0 $? Or, is that assumption necessary for more general reasons?

Comment: If $f$ is as in the question, then $f$ is continuous, and the sublevel sets are closed.

Comment: @daw If the closedness of $U$ is assumed, is the distance function enough to construct such a convex function?